# Lamentablemente la aplicacion Agenda se detuvo. Espero que puedan ayudarme

Tags: java, android

[image: Esto es lo que me sale en el Android Monitor]estoy programando en android studio, coloque un Button y este me llevara a otra actividad, el problema es que al presionar el boton me sale un error: Lamentablemente la aplicacion Agenda se detuvo. Espero que puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Probablemente nadie te va poder ayudar si no compartes ni código, ni excepción. Comparte tu código, haz una depuración, comparte la excepción completa y se te puede ayudar.

Comment: Pues pueden ser una infinidad de causas, si no agregas el mensaje desplegado en el LogCat es dificil adivinar la causa.... SI quieres desarrollar en Android es importante sepas usar el LogCat para no perder tiempo en problemas que pueden ser sencillos de resolver.

Comment: Espero que con esta imagen ya puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Hola Spartan456, lamentablemente las imágenes no sirven de mucho. En su lugar, es preferible que aportes un [mcve]. Échale un vistazo a [ask] y al [tour] para aprender algo más sobre SOes.

Comment: Ya pude solucionar el error, tuve que volver a crear la clase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definiste `android:OnClick` desde el layout, recuerda que de esta forma no tienes que agregar un listener si no el mètodo que definiste por ejemplo:

```
android:OnClick=miMetodo
```

El mètodo declarado debe recibir como parametro la vista para que funcione correctamente:

```
public void miMetodo(View view){
...
...
}
```